# htaccess redirect error - What's wrong?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

In localhost, I would like to make a redirect, but I don't understand what's wrong.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127.0.0.1
RewriteRule $ namepage.php [R=302, L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have spaces inbetween flags, it gets parsed as a separate parameter for the `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteRule $ namepage.php [R=302,L]
```

Comment: But Redirect not working, why?
`Redirect /page1.php page2.php`
On localhost

Comment: You'll have to provide more info about that, you didn't mention anything about a `Redirect` directive.